# PHP Mailer | No llegan los correos y sale mensaje raro al enviar

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, mailer

Tengo un problema hace ya varios días y no estoy encontrando una solucion por ningun lado, primero probe con php mail, y no me funcionaba y me recomendaron usar php mailer, pero de igual manera creo que el servidor de correo seguro no funciona o nose que pasa.., me sale que el mensaje es enviado y sale un mensaje raro, mi codigo es el siguiente.
Formulario HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FORMULARIO</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="PHPMailer-master/enviarmail.php" method="post">
        <h3>Nombre</h3>
        <input type="text" name="nombre">
        <h3>Apellido</h3>
        <input type="text" name="apellido">
        <h3>Mensaje</h3>
        <textarea name="mensaje"></textarea>
        Enviar
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Codigo php:

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader

require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();   
                                       // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'single-priva4.privatednsorg.com:465';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'contacto@cygnus.com.py';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'Juanse123.';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to


   $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
   $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
   $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'CURSO';
    $mail->Body    = 'NOMBRE: ' . $nombre . "<br>Apellido: " . $apellido . "<br>Mensaje: " . $mensaje ;
    $mail->AltBody = 'Ejemplo de BODY 2';

    $mail->send();

    echo 'Mensaje enviado';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

Al ejecutar en mi hosting, me sale mensaje enviado y este mensaje:

```
2018-08-16 15:18:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-single-priva4.privatednsorg.com ESMTP Exim 4.91 #1 Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:18:56 -0400 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.cygnus.com.py
2018-08-16 15:18:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-single-priva4.privatednsorg.com Hello www.cygnus.com.py [65.60.62.226]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2018-08-16 15:18:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2018-08-16 15:18:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2018-08-16 15:18:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<contacto@cygnus.com.py>
2018-08-16 15:18:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<web-7dxcj@mail-tester.com>
2018-08-16 15:18:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2018-08-16 15:18:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:18:56 -0400
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Juan Portillo <web-7dxcj@mail-tester.com>
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Juan <contacto@cygnus.com.py>
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: CURSO
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <DESKyjWHbKeCItedA7v19pxw5c4LEPadZQO26CnMQ@www.cygnus.com.py>
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.0.5 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_DESKyjWHbKeCItedA7v19pxw5c4LEPadZQO26CnMQ"
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_DESKyjWHbKeCItedA7v19pxw5c4LEPadZQO26CnMQ
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Ejemplo de BODY 2
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_DESKyjWHbKeCItedA7v19pxw5c4LEPadZQO26CnMQ
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: NOMBRE: Juan <br>Apellido: Portillo<br>Mensaje: ghdfhgfgfj
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_DESKyjWHbKeCItedA7v19pxw5c4LEPadZQO26CnMQ--
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-08-16 15:18:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2018-08-16 15:18:57 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1fqK36-00FSCv-FF
2018-08-16 15:18:57 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-08-16 15:18:57 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 single-priva4.privatednsorg.com closing connection
Mensaje enviado
```

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia pero si envías un correo no debes colocar el destinatario???; en tu codigo PHP no veo el correo y nombre del destinatario... me refiero a esto: `$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User'); `

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estás habilitando el debug. Prueba a comentar esta linea:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

así:

```
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Lo 'raro' que estás viendo es las comunicaciones (protocolo SMTP) entre tu cliente y el servidor smtp.

[Aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_para_transferencia_simple_de_correo) tienes más información al respecto por si te interesara el tema. Dentro además encontrarás un ejemplo sencillo de envío de e-mail, que ya de paso reproduzco aquí abajo:

C = Cliente; S = Servidor

```
S: 220 Servidor SMTP
C: HELO miequipo.midominio.com
S: 250 Hello, please to meet you
C: MAIL FROM: <yo@midominio.com>
S: 250 Ok
C: RCPT TO: <destinatario@sudominio.com>
S: 250 Ok
C: DATA
S: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
C: Subject: Campo de asunto
C: From: yo@midominio.com
C: To: destinatario@sudominio.com
C:
C: Hola,
C: Esto es una prueba.
C: Hasta luego.
C:
C: .
C: <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
S: 250 Ok: queued as 12345
C: quit
S: 221 Bye
```

Como verás, tiene una estructura similar a la que te estás encontrando. Pero eso es algo que debe pasar 'internamente', no es algo que debiera ver el usuario. Si lo ves tú es porque se debe estar adjuntando una copia de toda la documentación como cuerpo del mensaje debido a la opción de debug.

En definitiva, prueba quitando la opción de debug.

Comment: Ya lo eh intentado, solamente ya me sale mensaje enviado solamente, pero no llega en mi correo, ni en correos no deseados...

Comment: Lastimosamente estoy hace varios dias de esa manera, no logro hacer que funcione, pero con gmail funciona

Comment: Cuando dices que funciona con gmail, a qué te refieres? A gmail como destinatario? O a gmail como servidor smtp?

Comment: Si, como destinatario, usando un correo de gmail como destinatario sin problemas llega el correo, el servidor de correo que uso creo que es el problema...

Comment: cuál es el destinatario? web-7dxcj@mail-tester.com?

Comment: no, ese solo fue un mail de testeo... el otro mail de servidor de la empresa que es @cygnus.com.py

Answer (score -1):

Puedes intentar esto php tiene la función mailto y es fácil de usar
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hola esto no es una respuesta es un comentario que deseas que el OP realice una prueba.